# How do I find out why a device is not compatible with my app

Tags: android

I know this question had been asked in different versions already many times, but none of the answers helped me. I developped an app, that works fine on my mobile phone, but often can not be installed on the phones of my friends. I checked the device features my app needs, but they don't seem very unusual. the android minSdkVersion is also ok, and the apk has a normal size

I can not reproduce this problem on the emulator. even one of my apps, which is not compatible with my tablet on Google play, works perfectly when I run it locally while developing. so how do I find out, what device feature, or what other problem is preventing my app from being installed?

Here is the link to one of my apps on google play that causes this problem: [serial call](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.richardlederer.serialcall)

Comment: If the version of the device is below the minSdkVersion defined in your application, then it wont work.

Comment: i know, that was the first thing i checked, and that's why i wrote that the android version is ok. i have the same setting for my other apps, but some work, others dont.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the "problem" is your  *android:minSdkVersion* value.
[android:minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: Maybe you block some devices or countries from downloading.

Comment: but the mobile phones it talk about are from the same country

Comment: i wrote to google play and they talked something about device features. but they could not anser my question, how to find out which one is making the problem

Comment: The device features are declared by  _<uses-feature>_  in your manifest file. For example Bluetooth or Compass Sensor

Comment: yes i know of course, but i need to find out which feature creates the problem. i can not use the device that creates this problem, and i can not reproduce it in the emulator.

Comment: I don't really know how to help you with that. We don
't even know which features you are using. You should check the features of your friends phone and compare them to your app's features.

Comment: you can see the features i use in the google play link i posted. i was just wondering if there is any way to get the information which features don't match with witch phone, because i have no possibility to test my app on those phones.

Answer (score 0):

Check min sdk version in manifest file under app folder in android studio. Match with device's api level and change it accordingly.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.my.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```